# Blank output with system function

Tags: php

When I execute my script with console "php5 -f myfile.php" I have output, But when I open it with browser I see nothing.

```
<?php

 $cmd=system("cat /root/pays.log |awk '{print $4}' |uniq");
 echo $cmd;

?>
```

Comment: Does i show up in the console of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your web-server user doesn't have access to the **root* folder. 
try to move *pays.log* to a location which your web-server can get into. also make sure the correct permission is applied on the file itself as well.

Comment: I change the path of log file and everything it's ok thnx

Comment: You're most welcome, appreciate if you could accept the answer :)  and please remember to up-vote (if it helped) when you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the `system()` function is disabled.

There are two possible reasons for this.

1. The safe mode is active
2. The function is in the list of disabled functions

You can check the if the safe mode is active by `ini_get('safe_mode')`. That gives you a `0` if it is not active. More information here: [PHP: safe-mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)

The disabled functions are also a ini value. You can fetch it by `ini_get('disable_functions')`. It contains a comma separated list of the disabled functions. If `system` is inside the list, it will not work. More information here: [PHP: disable-functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)

It is pretty common for functions like `system` to be disabled.